# Error getting sections of BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Part of the program that I am creating requires that I ask the user for a character, convert it into a string, and then get individual sections of a buffered image, where the sections are the dimensions of the character/string.

However, the problem occurs when I try to go through the image section by section. The error occurs before the end of the first row of sections of the image, and it has to do with an out of bounds error, like the section of the buffered image I am requesting is outside of the actual dimensions of the buffered image I have.

My Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bufferedimageHeight; i += characterHeight) {
  for(int j = 0; j < bufferedimageWidth; j += characterWidth) {
    if (myMethod(mybufferedimage.getSubimage(i, j, characterWidth, characterHeight))) {
      // TODO CODE HERE
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the actual error message, and you really should do some of your own debugging such as putting in println's to test the actual diminsions of the BufferedImage and the values of your getSubimage parameters.

Comment: 1) *"Any help would be much appreciated."* As would a specific question.  Your question is what? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) *"has to do with an out of bounds error"*  Copy/paste exception output as an edit to the question.

Comment: I have done all of the debugging things you suggested, and the error still exits: `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside raster`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bufferedimageHeight-characterHeight; i += characterHeight) {
  for(int j = 0; j < bufferedimageWidth-characterWidth; j += characterWidth)
```

Comment: Although that seemed to work at first, I keep getting errors...so here's all of my code (because I can't figure it out after a very long period of time): [click here for java files (stored on dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uk6lc5sz3e5nhg/mirBk-P19J) ...The error happens on line 113 (which says `if (isHalfFull(image.getSubimage(i, j, LETTER_WIDTH, LETTER_HEIGHT))) {`), and presumably inside the method use on that line.